# Windows store event Marshalled for a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-store-apps, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

I saw similar posts to this however while using advised dispatcher still i can't get rid of this error, my code is as follows:

Xaml:

```
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="LostFocus">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ValidateUserNameCommand}"
                   InputConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=UserNameTextBox}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

And ViewModel:

```
        public RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs> ValidateUserNameCommand
    { get; private set; }

    public ChooseUsernameViewModel(IServerService _server, INavigationServiceCustom _nav) 
    {
        Server = _server;
        Navigation = _nav;

        ValidateUserNameCommand = new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(async (e) => await ValidateUserName(e));
    }    

        private async Task ValidateUserName(RoutedEventArgs eArgs)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
            {
            }
            else
            {

                await Server.CheckUserName(UserName); 
            }
        }
```

The problem is caused by line: `await Server.CheckUserName(UserName);`

I tried:`

```
    private async Task ValidateUserName(RoutedEventArgs eArgs)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
async () =>
{
          await Server.CheckUserName(UserName); 
});

            }
        }`
```

and olso

```
            ValidateUserNameCommand = new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>(async (e) => await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
async() =>

await ValidateUserName(e)));
```

but the problem persists. Could somebody help me?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The point of using await is that whatever is on the right of the keyword runs asynchronously on a worker thread.  Whatever class implements IServerService apparently isn't very happy about that.  You'll need to fix it.  Use the debugger, make it stop on the first-chance exception to locate the code with the problem.  If it is not yours then use a telephone.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i narrowed it and found that its caused by SignalR Connsection.send

Comment: @Dirk Exception = {"The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))"} In serverService, I have method checkUsername that tries to send message to SignalR server (Connsection connection.send(Message)); this causes exception however still i have no idea how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - found that messenger in received response was at fault

Answer (score 1):

you should use CoreDispatcher instead of CoreWindow like this.

```
public CoreDispatcher dispatcher { get; set; }
   this.dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
   await this.dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                {
await Server.CheckUserName(UserName); 
});
```

Comment: This dosen't change anything